# Easiest way to get term entities from a term reference field?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

I always end up with lots of juggling to get seemingly simple things, like "All term names".

```
$field_terms = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, $tags_field);

if ($field_terms) {
  $tids = array();
  foreach ($field_terms as $field_term) {
    $tids[] = $field_term['tid'];
  }
  $terms = taxonomy_term_load_multiple($tids);

  $tags = '';
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $tags .= $term->name . ',';
  }
  $tags = rtrim($tags, ',');
}
```

Can anyone share any neat tricks for making the above easier?

The part that really annoys me is the first loop, that I need just to untangle the field api array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one annoys the bejesus out of me too. Things are slightly nicer using the entity API module, but it's still not pretty.

I've resorted to including a helper function in most projects now to extract an array of values for a single field column:

```
function _field_get_column_values($entity_type, $entity, $field_name, $column_name) {
  if ($field_items = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, $field_name)) {
    $values = array();
    foreach ($field_items as $item) {
      if (isset($item[$column_name])) {
        $values[] = $item[$column_name];
      }
    }
    return empty($values) ? FALSE : $values;
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```

Using that your code would shrink a little:

```
if ($tids = _field_get_column_values($entity_type, $entity, $tags_field, 'tid')) {
  $terms = taxonomy_term_load_multiple($tids);

  // ...
}
```

It's still not a great solution, but I find it saves a fair bit of time on projects that need a lot of custom code.

Comment: Thanks. :) While we're wrapping field_get_items, it always annoyed me that it returns false. Why not return an empty array instead? That would allow `foreach(array() as $item)`, unlike `foreach(FALSE as $item)`, which will yield a warning.

Comment: At a guess it's because `field_get_items` can be called for a non-existent field, and returning an empty array in that case would be semantically incorrect (it would suggest the field exists but just doesn't have any submitted values). I totally agree though, if the field exists and doesn't have any values it would make more sense to be given an empty array...I only return false from the wrapper function for consistency, I hadn't really thought about it before :)

Comment: Great, thanks again. Now using your method, re-written to always return an array. :)

Comment: @Clive `Things are slightly nicer using the entity API module` -- Could you elaborate a bit on that? Which functions from the Entity API module can you use on the current problem?

Comment: @GeorgJaehnig I was thinking along the lines of the `entity_metadata_wrapper` function. Whether it's 'nicer' depends on your take I guess, I personally prefer as much OO as I can get my hands on so in my world that's slightly nicer :)